# How do I make a JTextPane have a different tab size in Java?

Tags: java, jtextpane

I have a JTextPane, but I have noticed that if I use `.setText()` all tabs get removed.
To fix this I see two options:

1. Make the tabs get set properly.
2. Replace all tabs with the html special character `&#8195;` and then change the tab size in the JTextPane to match the width of the html tab.

I do not know how to do #1 so I am trying to use the crude hack #2.
So my question is, how do I change the tab size for JTextPane using an HTMLDocument, or how do I `setText()` and not have tabs be removed?

Also I am using `getText()` and `setText()` in order to save the text inside the JTextPane.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you got any code to show?

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757692/how-do-you-set-the-tab-size-in-a-jeditorpane) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22721955/java-jtextpane-tab-size).  You could also do a goggle search for "jtextpane tab size" to see more...

Comment: The code I have tried I have already removed.  I have goggled for hours on the tab size but every method did not work.

Comment: Try this http://java-sl.com/tip_default_tabstop_size.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve my problem without method 1 or 2 I have done this:

```
textPane.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("TAB"), "tab");
textPane.getActionMap().put("tab", new AbstractAction("tab"){
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2621537943352838927L;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        try {
            textPane.getDocument().insertString(textPane.getCaretPosition(), " ", null);//The " " is the html special character (tab) in plain text.
        } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

I found that this overrides the default tab input.